# running headless chrome in an microsoft azure web app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, google-chrome-headless

I am currently using phantomjs to generate screenshots of web pages.
Due to various issues including web fonts, and video tag support, I would like to try switching to headless chrome.

Has anyone had success running headless chrome in an azure web app?
I cannot find a .net api, and assume I need to run node.js with puppeteer If I want a javascript api similar to phantomjs.

Comment: https://github.com/kblok/puppeteer-sharp is a .NET Api that I've successfully used locally so far! Am working on getting it to work on Azure!

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to run chrome.exe on Azure, so I've gone to browserless.io for the moment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now most of the big libraries *are* made for NodeJS. It's possible to run Chrome headless without it, but you'll need a library for your .NET API to effectively communicate with Chrome. If none exist, then the protocol itself is documented [here](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/), and you could build one for .NET.

If you're struggling to get Chrome running on Azure I have a service that offers Docker images, which could be as simple as a few commands to have up and running (located [here](https://browserless.io/)). Other than that there's a few open-source options out there, but they have differing issues and uses-cases.